# Outdoor light fixture

Tags: electrical

I have a an old garage light fixture that has no metal box. The hot/cold wires go directly through the bricks with no ground wire.

Can I connect the ground wire to my mounting bracket screw?

Comment: You can but it will not be grounded if no ground wire/conduit back to the panel.  Will be as useful as just cutting it off.  Not having a box is probably the bigger problem.

Answer (score 1):

Connecting it to the bracket screw will do nothing for proper grounding.

Also, do not connect it to the neutral ("cold"). Leave it unconnected, and make sure it is capped and taped off so that it does not accidentally come in contact with any live ("hot") screw or wire cap inside that fixture.

In case you come across this on the internet, there is a type of grounding where wiring to a screw in brick would help, but this is *not* your case.

There are alternatives possible in your scenario, and it does not have to be unsafe the way you have it. For instance, if it is completely sealed from water (which it rarely is) and if there are no insects that can enter (also a tall order), this could be ok. One concern could be that the fixture becomes live ("hot") because there is an electrical path through moist insect parts and accumulated dust. But we would need more details to assess, through pictures, and some information about where the wall wire goes to.

Comment: The screw in a brick seems odd.  Would imagine electrical connectivity just a tiny bit better than air or plastic/rubber/dry wood.

Comment: @crip659 ...i was waiting for someone to catch on to that! screw in brick has been done for ESD protection. Not saying it's good, but it could be done. In any case, what's good for ESD is not at all going to work here. Just wanted that mentioned. BTW, your comment above would also be good as an answer.

Comment: Why in the heck would someone think they need ESD protection on a outside light fixture?

Comment: @SteveSh Not you not me. But they could google something with a collection of words and get some answer that they cannot triage. Happens a lot with medical, DIY, legal subjects. So the gist here is "if you read this on line, yes there is a place for it, but not in your case". In this case I didn't want there to be a false sense of safety.